# Insert one table from one table to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using MS SQL Server Express 2017.

I have an OrderDetails table.

```
OrderDetailID   OrderID ProductID   Quantity    Category
1               1       1           5           Local
2               1       3           2           Remote
3               1       2           5           Store
4               2       1           3           Local
5               2       2           5           Remote
6               2       3           2           Remote
```

I want to insert a new order detail with a category of 'Unavailable', by using an existing list of OrderID's. The list of OrderID's that I have are in a temp table with Int values for OrderID's that are already in the OrderDetails table.

For example: If in my temp table of order ID's I have 1 and 2 (orderID 1 and 2), I'd like to insert another OrderID 1 and OrderID 2 to the OrderDetails Table with the values I want, such as a category of 'Unavailable' (Category has a column data type of varchar(50), but I'd like for the Insert statement to use the same OrderID value from my temp table with existing OrderID's that I want to add.

My temp table (_tmpOrderIDs):

```
OrderID
1
2
```

So far I have this statement:

```
INSERT INTO OrderDetails
   (OrderID, ProductID, Quantity, Category) 
       VALUES ((SELECT OrderID FROM _tmpOrderIDs), 4, 1, 'Unavailable')
```

The error I get is 'Subquery returned more than 1 value.', which is right, because _tmpOrderIDs has more than one OrderID. But I want all those orderID's in _tmpOrderIDs to be inserted to the OrderDetails table using the custom values I give it, **while** keeping their own individual OrderID's the same, as they are - in the temp table, _tmpOrderIDs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO OrderDetails (OrderID, ProductID, Quantity, Category) 
    SELECT OrderID,  4, 1, 'Unavailable'
    FROM _tmpOrderIDs;
```

The `VALUES` keyword is not needed.

Comment: And note how you can always check that you are getting what you want, because the SELECT is indeed a "normal" Select statement......  you can develop and run that Select first, and see that indeed you get what you want to insert.